# query params on button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a paginated quiz which has multiple questions. I am using the next button to display questions and reload with query parameters. My code is adding parameters, but it adds a lot of query strings with each button click, for example: ?status=Active?status=Active?status=Active.

I want to add only one query string each time a user clicks, but the value should change as the user progresses through the questions. For example, for the first question: ?status=1 and for the second question: ?status=2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $(function () {
        $('[id*=next]').on('click', function () {
            var oldURL = window.location.href;
            var type = "Active";
            if (history.pushState) {
                var newUrl = oldURL + "?status=" + type;
                window.history.pushState({ path: newUrl }, '', newUrl);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

i tried to remove '', newUrl but nothing

Answer (score -1):

- First, in your code, the variable type = "Active" so the result is ?status=Active ? Are you mistake with type = "1" or sth.
- Second,when your href is "?status=Active", you click again, the new href will be "?status=Active?status=Active" and so on. You need to check your current href  is contain status or not to add ?status= or change ...=1 to =2 in your code.